# Pod gets recreated after deletion

Tags: kubernetes

I'm unable to delete the kubernetes pod, it keeps recreating it.
There's no service or deployment associated with the pod. There's a label on the pod thou, is that the root cause?
If I edit the label out with `kubectl edit pod podname` it removes the label from the pod, but creates a new pod with the same label at the same time. ¿?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pod can be created by ReplicationControllers or ReplicaSets. The latter one might be created by an Deployment. The described behavior strongly indicates, that the Pod is managed by either of these two.

You can check for these with this commands:

```
kubectl get rs
kubectl get rc
```